# How to send push to specific member using SNS topic?

Tags: amazon-web-services, push-notification, amazon-sns, aws-php-sdk

I am using AWS SNS to send a push notification, right now i am using `publish` method of `aws-php-sdk` to send push specific device. **My requirement is sent push to thousands of members within 30 seconds**. When i used publish method it takes 5min to send 1000 users. 
I have read about `topic` it sends multiple members at once, but my scenario is i want to send push to specific users, not all topic users.

For example, i register 10,000 members in one topic, but from this 10,000 some time i am sending 9000, sometimes 1000 members.

So anyone has an idea how to send push using topic but specific members only.

I also think another case, every time i create new topic and register member to this topic and then send a message to him and then delete `topic`, but here every time when register member it is also taking time. So if you have an idea to register multiple members at once then it will also be helpful for me.

Below is my current code to send push.

```
    $arn = "user arn";
    $sns = new Aws\Sns\SnsClient(array(
                    'version' => 'latest',
                    'key' => my_aws_key,
                    'secret' => aws_secret,
                    'region' => region,
                    'profile' => profile_name,
                    'debug' => false,
                    'http' => array('verify' => false)
                ));
$appArn = "application arn";

$sns->publish(array('Message' => '{ "GCM": "{\"data\": { \"message\": \" This is my message \"} }"}',
                     'MessageStructure' => 'json',
                     'TargetArn' => $arn
                        ));
```

Comment: Are you doing it `synchronous`? If so, try to do it `asynchronous`.

Comment: I am sending it using a cron job file.

Comment: Well, this is okay. But is your PHP Code running `synchronous` (one by one)?

Comment: yes, i am sending one by one member using foreach loop. this loop execute 1000 time if i am sending it 1000 member. How can i optimize it. ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying many solutions i am able to send thousands of notification within one minute, here i am showing code how i do it, I have done with `php` `multicurl` functionality, so i execute multiple parallel processes and all process send notification simultaneously.

**Define multi curl and prepare URL to send notification**

Suppose i have 5,000 members and i have array of it's token and other member details `$device_type_ids_arr`
I part of all member to 500 bunch, so each time curl execute it sends notification to 500 members

```
$_datas = array_chunk($device_type_ids_arr, 500);
/*initialise multi curl*/
$mh = curl_multi_init();
$handles = array();
/* Perform loop for each 500 members batch */
foreach ($_datas as $batchPart) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    $postData['devices'] = $batchPart;
    $postData['push_content'] = $push_content;
    $data_string = json_encode($postData);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, base_url() . "EmailPipe/sendNotification/"); //your URL to call amazon service (Explain below)
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'User-Agent: curl/7.39.0');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Content-Length:' . strlen($data_string))
    );
    curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $ch);
    $handles[] = $ch;
}
// execute requests and poll periodically until all have completed
$isRunning = null;
do {
    curl_multi_exec($mh, $isRunning);
} while ($isRunning > 0);

/* Once all execution are complete remove curl handler */
foreach ($handles as $ch) {
    curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $ch);
}
/* Close multi curl */
curl_multi_close($mh);
```

**Function which is received `curl` request and send notification**

```
function sendCurlSignal() {
    require_once APPPATH . 'libraries/aws-sdk/aws-autoloader.php';
    $pipeArr = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
    $push_content = $pipeArr["push_content"];
    $device_id_arr = $pipeArr["devices"];
    $sns = new Aws\Sns\SnsClient(array(
        'version' => 'latest',
        'key' => "Amazon key",
        'secret' => "Amazon secret",
        'region' => "region like eu-west-1",
        'profile' => "Amazon account user",
        'debug' => false,
        'http' => array('verify' => false)
    ));
    $appArn = "SNS application arn";
    $promises = $results = $retArr = array();

    foreach ($device_id_arr as $key => $device_detail) {
        $arn = $device_detail['arn']; /* SNS ARN of each device */
        $token = $device_detail['token_id']; /* Registered token */
        $userid = $device_detail['member_id'];
        /* If you don't have arn then add arn for specific token in amazon */
        if (empty($arn)) {
            try {
                $updatedArn = $sns->createPlatformEndpoint(array('PlatformApplicationArn' => $appArn, 'Token' => $token));
                $arn = $newArn = isset($updatedArn['EndpointArn']) ? $updatedArn['EndpointArn'] : "";
                //update member detail with new arn
                if ($newArn != "" && $userid != "" && $token != "") {
                    /* You can update arn into database for this member */
                }
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                /* Get error if any */
                $errorMsg = $e->getMessage();
                $newFile = fopen("error_arn_fail.txt", "a+");
                fwrite($newFile, "Member Id:" . $userid . "\r\nToken:" . $token . "\r\n" . $errorMsg . "\r\n");
                fclose($newFile);
            }
        }
        if (!empty($arn)) {
            try {
                $promises[$userid] = $sns->publishAsync(array(
                    'Message' => '{ "GCM": "{\"data\": { \"message\": \"' . $push_content . '\" } }"}',
                    'MessageStructure' => 'json',
                    'TargetArn' => $arn
                ));
                $promises[$userid]->arn = $arn;
                $promises[$userid]->token = $token;
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                $errorMsg = $e->getMessage();
                $newFile = fopen("error_async_fail_signal.txt", "a+");
                fwrite($newFile, $errorMsg . "\r\n");
                fclose($newFile);
            }
        }
    }
    /* Broadcast push notification */
    $results = \GuzzleHttp\Promise\settle($promises)->wait(TRUE);

    /* if you want to get result of broadcast and sent message id then do following */
    foreach ($results as $key => $value) {
        if (isset($value['reason'])) {
            /* Reason come in case of fail */
            $message = $value['reason']->getMessage();
            $token = (isset($promises[$key]->token)) ? $promises[$key]->token : "";
            $arn = (isset($promises[$key]->arn)) ? $promises[$key]->arn : "";
            if (empty($arn) || empty($token) || empty($key)) {
                $newFile = fopen("error_empty_detail_result.txt", "a+");
                fwrite($newFile, "Member Id:" . $key . "\r\nArn:" . $arn . "\r\nToken:" . $token . "\r\n");
                fclose($newFile);
            }
            /* Handle error */
            if (strpos($message, "Endpoint is disabled") !== false && $token != "" && $arn != "") {
                try {
                    $res = $sns->setEndpointAttributes(array(
                        'Attributes' => array("Token" => $token, "Enabled" => "true"),
                        'EndpointArn' => $arn
                    ));
                } catch (Exception $e) {
                    $errorMsg = $e->getMessage();
                    $newFile = fopen("error_endpoint_disable.txt", "a+");
                    fwrite($newFile, "Member Id:" . $key . "\r\nArn:" . $arn . "\r\nToken:" . $token . "\r\n" . $errorMsg . "\r\n");
                    fclose($newFile);
                }
            }
            if (strpos($message, "No endpoint found for the target arn specified") !== false && $token != "") {
                try {
                    $updatedArn = $sns->createPlatformEndpoint(array('PlatformApplicationArn' => $appArn, 'Token' => $token));
                    $arn = $newArn = isset($updatedArn['EndpointArn']) ? $updatedArn['EndpointArn'] : "";
                    //update member detail with new arn
                    if ($newArn != "" && !empty($key) && $token != "") {
                        /* You can update arn into database for this member */
                    }
                } catch (Exception $e) {
                    $errorMsg = $e->getMessage();
                    $newFile = fopen("error_arn_fail.txt", "a+");
                    fwrite($newFile, "Member Id:" . $key . "\r\nToken:" . $token . "\r\n" . $errorMsg . "\r\n");
                    fclose($newFile);
                }
            }
            /* After handle error resed notification to this users */
            if (!empty($arn)) {
                try {
                    $publishRes = $sns->publish(array(
                        'Message' => '{ "GCM": "{\"data\": { \"message\": \"' . $push_content . '\" } }"}',
                        'MessageStructure' => 'json',
                        'TargetArn' => $arn
                    ));
                    $retArr[$key] = $publishRes->get("MessageId");
                } catch (Exception $e) {
                    $errorMsg = $e->getMessage();
                    $newFile = fopen("error_push_not_sent.txt", "a+");
                    fwrite($newFile, "Member Id:" . $key . "\r\nARN:" . $arn . "\r\nToken:" . $token . "\r\n" . $errorMsg . "\r\n");
                    fclose($newFile);
                }
            }
        } else {
            $retArr[$key] = $results[$key]['value']->get("MessageId");
        }
    }

    /* All member data get into one array to perform database operation */
    if (isset($retArr) && !empty($retArr)) {
        /* in $retArr you get each member amazon message id */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to use `publishAsync()` method.

```
$userArnCollection = array(
    'arn:XXX',
    'arn:YYY',
    'arn:ZZZ',
);
$sns = new Aws\Sns\SnsClient(array(
    'version' => 'latest',
    'key'     => my_aws_key,
    'secret'  => aws_secret,
    'region'  => region,
    'profile' => profile_name,
    'debug'   => false,
    'http'    => array('verify' => false)
));

foreach ($userArnCollection as $userArn) {
    $sns->publishAsync(array(
        'Message'          => '{ "GCM": "{\"data\": { \"message\": \" This is my message \"} }"}',
        'MessageStructure' => 'json',
        'TargetArn'        => $userArn
    ));
}
```

**EDIT**

Example with promise handling

```
$userArnCollection = array(
    'arn:XXX',
    'arn:YYY',
    'arn:ZZZ',
);
$sns = new Aws\Sns\SnsClient(array(
    'version' => 'latest',
    'key'     => my_aws_key,
    'secret'  => aws_secret,
    'region'  => region,
    'profile' => profile_name,
    'debug'   => false,
    'http'    => array('verify' => false)
));

$promises = array();
foreach ($userArnCollection as $userArn) {
    $promises[] = $sns->publishAsync(array(
        'Message'          => '{ "GCM": "{\"data\": { \"message\": \" This is my message \"} }"}',
        'MessageStructure' => 'json',
        'TargetArn'        => $userArn
    ));
}

$results = \GuzzleHttp\Promise\unwrap($promises);
```

Comment: Right now i am using this method. But for example, here i have 1000 arn then it will take too much time. What difference if i use `publishAsync` method rather than `publish` method.

Comment: If you are using `publishAsync` the requests are running `asynchronous` (in parallel). For more informations check: [Promises](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/guide/promises.html)

Comment: Yes, it is faster than `publish` method.

Comment: Is this method send notification immediately from amazon? it seems it taking time.

Comment: in `publishAsync` i can not receive push.

Comment: Basically it should work as `publish` (send immediately + you should receive push notifications)... Did you check if you receive exceptions?

Comment: No it did not give any exception. When i try to print result of `$sns->publishAsync()` It is giving too large array and browser is hang.

Comment: When is use `$result->wait();` then i receive push but it is taking same time as `publish` method.

Comment: Did you read the article i linked? [Executing commands concurrently](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/guide/promises.html#executing-commands-concurrently)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147606/discussion-between-jitendra-and-maikay).

Comment: Yes, i read it but there is example of bucket and dynamoDB. which is not useful for me

Comment: yes, it works but still, it can not compete for my requiremets :( . I need to send 10,000 push within 30 seconds. Here i  send 100 and takes 5second. Do you have any much better idea?

Comment: When i use `$promises` it does not send push more than 2000. Any limit in `$promises array`?

Comment: @Jitendra have you solved this ? please post your answer

Comment: Yes, i have solved but this is actually not done through `sns topic`, i solve it another way

Comment: @NirmalGoswami see my posted answer, hope it will help you.

Comment: @Jitendra Thanks